# Crawling infobox section of wikipedia using scraperwiki is giving error

Tags: python, wikipedia, scraperwiki

I am newb to **scraperwiki**.I am trying to get **infobox** from wiki page using **scraperwiki**. I get the idea of scraperwiki to crawl wiki pages from below link

> https://blog.scraperwiki.com/2011/12/how-to-scrape-and-parse-wikipedia/

**Code**

```
import scraperwiki

wikipedia_utils = scraperwiki.swimport("wikipedia_utils")

title = "Aquamole Pot"

val = wikipedia_utils.GetWikipediaPage(title)
res = wikipedia_utils.ParseTemplates(val["text"])
print res               # prints everything we have found in the text
infobox_ukcave = dict(res["templates"]).get("Infobox ukcave")
print infobox_ukcave    # prints just the ukcave infobox
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrap_wiki.py", line 3, in <module>
    wikipedia_utils = scraperwiki.swimport("wikipedia_utils")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'swimport'
```

Comment: What Python are you using ? Scraperwiki seems compatible only with Python 2.7(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scraperwiki)  A general consideration. This blog you cited is 3 years old and many things could have changed. Why not focus directly on scrapy and start by there ?

Comment: My python version is 2.7. How to crawl using scrapy?

Comment: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/overview.html there are many examples and there is support here on SO